# Decorate a function in a library

Tags: c++, linux, overriding, shared-libraries, decorator

I have a shared library that I need to write tests for. Let's say there's a function called func() in the library:

```
// from the library
<some_type> func(<some_params>); // signature of the function func
```

Library's documentation states that this function must be called under certain conditions. So to test that requirement I write my own function func() of the same signature in a test file:

```
// test.cpp
bool is_func_called = false;
<some_type> func(<some_params>) {
    is_func_called = true;
}
```

Is this approach correct? Is my implementation of the func() guaranteed to override the implementation in the library?

And sometimes it's necessary to be able to decorate the func() from a library (instead of overriding it):

```
// test.cpp
bool is_func_called = false;
<some_type> func(<some_params>) {
    is_func_called = true;
    func(); // a call to the implementation in the library
}
```

How can I access the implementation in the library if I have overridden it?

Environment: Ubuntu, g++.

I'm currently working with a shared library. But I'm actually interested in both (shared and static libraries).

Comment: If you define exactly the same signature, then the linker will complain of a duplicate.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It somehow chooses my implementation

Comment: You cannot have double definition of a function. If for purpose of testing you only link with your own implementation, not with library, this should be fine. But I'd recommend using Dependency Injection and some nice testing library (e.g. [GoogleMock](https://github.com/google/googletest) ) instead of implemnting this functionality on your own.

Comment: Static or dynamic library? For a dynamic library you could use [the `LD_PRELOAD` *trick*](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/low-level/kernel/2016/08/29/16-48-53-the_-ld_preload-_trick/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm currently working with a shared library. But I'm actually interested in both.

Comment: First sentence says about testing library, second sentence says something about mocking library. So where is exactly code you wan't to test? In library (dll) or in host application/library? So where is your code?

Comment: The func() is in the library. But there's a requirement that this function must be called under certain conditions, and  this conditions are out of the scope of the library itself. So I have to test that the function func() is really called when the conditions are met. I create the conditions in the test.cpp and expect the func() to be called.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD trick on Linux.

Compile your own implementation of `func()` into shared library.

```
gcc -shared -fPIC func.c -o func.so
```

Then in shell prompt

```
> LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD=func.so ./main
```

and your version of func() will be called.

If you want to chain calls - decorate original func() with your func() first, then code shall look like this

```
typedef a (*original_func_type)(B b);

a func(B b) {
    ... // whatever code you want
    original_func_type orig_func;
    orig_func = (original_func_type)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "func");
    return orig_func(b);
}
```

Is that what you want?

UPDATE

More wordly [tutorial](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/). Another [tutorial](https://catonmat.net/simple-ld-preload-tutorial). Link to [tutorial on symbols/linking](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f10/www/lectures/11-linking.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just want to say that my approach to override a function is actually working. I have tried it. Is it correct?

Comment: @embedc Well, it should work, linker shall pick up your implementation first. True decoration/chaining like I wrote is a lot more interesting for testing, inspection and injection purpose. Added link to another two-parts tutorial.

Comment: Could you please explain why the linker shall pick up my implementation first? Is there a rule about it or something?

Comment: @embedc Typical symbol from shared library would be weak one. Typical code in one of the .o file would produce strong symbol. Strong symbol would be picked up first by linker. Added another tutorial link wrt symbols on Linux.

Comment: @embedc you could check symbols in .o, .so files with the help of `nm`, `objdump` or `readelf`